# OpenCV-3 with inbuilt CUDA libraries/functionality

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, cuda, opencv3.0

I have downloaded `opencv.exe` provided by the official website. I configured my visual studio 10 as per this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ScAPinibluA).

Now, I am able to compile and run a simple code given below:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout<<"opencv Version: "<<CV_VERSION <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Problem:** But as soon as I try to include the header for `cuda` (i.e. `#include "cuda.hpp"`), it throws an error `fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cuda.h': No such file or directory`.

**PS:** I am able to compile and run a standalone cuda program as shown in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ed_h2km0liI).

I have checked that `cuda.h` is present in the folder `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v7.0\include`.

Comment: how about `#include <opencv2/cuda.hpp>` ? if this does not solve your problem, you must be more specific. what does "does not recognize it" mean? post the exact error messages.

Comment: @m.s. : no, it didn't help either. I have updated my question to be more specific about "it does not recognize it".

Comment: are the CUDA include directories added to Visual Studio?

Comment: @m.s. : I have tried to run a standalone code for cuda as I have mentioned in my original post, and it worked.

Comment: yes, but does the project where you combine OpenCV and CUDA have the correct include paths set? or is this the same project?

Comment: @m.s. : Why do I need to add the directory of cuda separately for an openCV program?? Cuda's image processing library should be a part of opencv libraries and I have already included the path of opencv libraries. I want to use openCV's libraries for image processing which use cuda functionality. For example: `cv::cuda::demosaicing ()` should be a part of OpenCV's library and hence I don't think that I need to include the libraries of cuda explicitly.

Comment: OpenCV uses CUDA's core functionality (memory management, launching kernels etc.) hence it requires CUDA include files and libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build OpenCV libraries along with CUDA libraries then, you don't need to set the path of CUDA libraries/headers explicitly. I followed the installation method which is [suggested here](https://initialneil.wordpress.com/2014/09/25/opencv-2-4-9-cuda-6-5-visual-studio-2013/) .

I included the following headers in my OpenCV code and they worked fine.

```
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"
#include "opencv2\core\cuda.hpp"
#include "opencv2\core\cuda\filters.hpp"
#include "opencv2\cudaarithm.hpp"
#include "opencv2\cudafilters.hpp"
#include "opencv2\cudaimgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2\cudalegacy.hpp"
```